# I'm working on a portfolio project in Angular 17. My Html Classes are not taking effect

Tags: html, css, visual-studio-code, angular17

```
<nav class="navbar-expand-md border-bottom mb-3">
    <div class="container">
        <ul class="nav justify-content-center">
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link text-secondary">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link text-secondary">Portfolio</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link text-secondary">Resume</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link text-secondary">Contact</a>
            </li>
            
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

The classes for navbar are not taking effect and the browser lists the items to the left side. Why are the classes not taking effect? My CSS file is empty so far. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Your classes (e.g., `justify-content-center`) have to be defined somewhere, in your CSS file or in your HTML file.

Comment: thank you, adding that in the CSS template was a temporary fix. It was actually bootstrap not taking effect I just had add the path manually to Angular.Json. Visual studio code apparently does not do it automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you are using bootstrap. Try installing bootstrap. if not working still,
Delete node_modules folder and run "npm install". Hopefully that will work

For more details about bootstrap see [here](https://getbootstrap.com/)

Comment: Thank you Rahul, that was it. I had needed to reinstall bootstrap, and then add it onto the Angular.Json styles section for it work.